# How to edit a bin/img file's magic number?

Tags: firmware

I'm trying to flash a router to openwrt, but the factory firmware don't accept the firmware "...invalid configuration...bad magic number..."

I can extract both factory.img and openwrt.bin using 7z, but the router just refuse any third-party firmware.

So how can I read out the factory magic number and write them to the custom image file?

Comment: This error message indicates that you're doing something improperly. Flashing the image with just magic number changed will most likely brick your router.

Comment: The message is because the factory firmware don't allow anything not from factory, but I want to put a 3rd-party firmware on it. The Openwrt forum have a discuss on this model, and they use TTL cable to hack it from boot, but I don't have the cable and I want try this way.

Comment: If it was possible this was, developers would already do it this way and provide people with a pre-made package. But apparently they were unable to do so and decided that another method is more feasible, so it's unlikely we'll be able to figure it out.